# Rust initialize generic type

Tags: rust

I've got a complex chunk of code that I've outlined below.  Basically I need to initialize a generic, its always a struct and that struct has Default implemented, but the compiler still complains:

```
fn create<T: Default>() -> T
{
    T { ..Default::default() }
}

fn main()
{
    let mut x = create::<Bob>();
}
```

Yields:

```
error[E0574]: expected struct, variant or union type, found type parameter `T`
  --> macro.rs:71:5
   |
71 |     T { ..Default::default() }
   |     ^ not a struct, variant or union type

error: aborting due to previous error
```

Is there a way to tell rust that T is always a struct or something?

Thanks,

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I doubt you can perform exactly this code. By using curly braces we tell the compiler that we initialize a `struct`. But the generic types can't be structs, generic can be only traits with lifetimes. For example, you can't insist on using structs only in the generic code, but you may insist on some requirements, which is implementation of `Default` trait here. So, in your generic function code, the only thing you may expect is the `Default` trait. To use it, you must write the appropriate code which uses the trait:

```
fn create<T: Default>() -> T
{
    T::default()
}
```

This code will use `T`'s `Default` implementation by calling `default()` method on it.

Comment: @LukeDupin glad to hear :)